# To add string at the end of matched line with directory structure using linux commands

Tags: linux, shell

I have a requirement to add values at the end of a file which matches the string using linux command. The problem is that the string which we are adding at the end of file contains directory structure and the sed utility is not able to handle that.

**Sample File:**

```
192.168.2.3 domain.com
192.168.2.3 domain2.com
```

**Expected Output**

add value[/home/user/directory] to the matched string [192.168.2.3]

```
192.168.2.3 domain.com
192.168.2.3 domain2.com /home/user/directory
```

Comment: 192.168.2.3 is matched in both lines. Why add only to second line? Does this check for IP should happen only in the last line?

Comment: my bad the actual file is 
192.168.2.5 domain.com
192.168.2.3 domain2.com

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
awk -v home="$HOME" '/192\.168\.2\.3/{$0= $0 FS  home}1' file
```

If the line contains the IP pattern, appends home directory to the current line

Comment: I tried the same thing with below file but it didnt work out

HeaderType~!Common
Section~!Yes~![GENERAL]
KeyValue~!Yes~!Key1#[GENERAL]

awk -v home="/home/directory" 'Key1#[GENERAL]{$0= $0 FS  home}1' file.txt

Comment: When you post a question, ensure the format of the sample file matches with your original requirement. Your question has something, and the file you are trying with has something else.

Comment: the new file format put in the comment is not clear. You need to update your original question itself for us to understand.